# Error when importing Tensorflow - Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\richa\Documents\_Projects_\Astr0loger\interface.py", line 26, in <module>
    from controller import choose_best_stocks
  File "C:\Users\richa\Documents\_Projects_\Astr0loger\controller.py", line 10, in <module>
    from trainer import get_data, train_model, test_model
  File "C:\Users\richa\Documents\_Projects_\Astr0loger\trainer.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/richa/Documents/_Projects_/Astr0loger/astrology_env/Lib/site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Apparently there are three common causes/fixes to the problem:

1. Python is 32 bit while the system is 64 bit, or vice versa. I checked, that is not the case.
2. cpu doesn't support AVX2 instructions - I tried tensorflow-gpu, same issue, so I don't think that's it
3. You need to install the MSVC 2019 redistributable - I checked, I have it

AAAAAAAAAAH What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out the error was fixed by installing an older version of Tensorflow; 2.0.0. If you're having the same issue, try several versions of tensorflow.